# Cannot move object with NavMeshAgent in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't move uploaded models in the Unity with NavMeshAgent. They just walk while standing still. And whenever I start the game it gets it's "y" position as something different than it should be. This might be the problem but there's nothing that changes the position.[image]

Comment: I can move the cubes and stuff tho. They're okay.

Comment: Can you share code and inspector of your updated model?

Comment: Sure. But I don't think it has anything to do with code, because it works on normal objects such as cubes and more.

Comment: This is the inspector: https://imgur.com/a/7OnNeW5
This is the code: https://codeshare.io/Od8PPx

Answer (score 0):

To use NavMeshAgent you need to add Rigidbody component to your uploaded model and also bake your NavMesh like terrain, obstacles and so on.